# Audio amp board keep blowing fuses

Tags: audio, fuses, debugging

I have a electronic piano that stopped working. After opening I case I found that one fuse on the amplifier PCB had blown. I replaced the fuses but they immediately blew again. I have investigated the board. I found that the top one 4700uF capacitor was protruding up a bit more that the others, plus there was some sort of goop on the base of the capacitor(s). I'm not sure if that's coming off of the capacitor or if it was just glue?
[image: Picture of the board in its initial environment]

[image: Picture of the capacitor that looks blown]

[image: Picture of the residue found on the board after removing the capacitor]

Anyway, long story short, I replaced all 4700uF on the board, but the fuses keep blowing up anyway.

Any idea what to investigate next? I have access to a multimeter and an oscilloscope. I am currently tracing the PCB schematics, but I was hoping there would be an obvious culprit.

[image: The main chip in the center of the board is a LA4725]
[image: A picture of the board]

Comment: The cap on the left does look like it is bulging. It is unlikely the capacitors are causing the fuses to blow, I’d suspect the audio chip. Nevertheless,the caps look low quality and suspect. So I’d be replacing them.

Answer (score 1):

Any bulging capacitors are bad. If some are bulging the rest are suspect. The ‘goop’ on the bottom is glue.

You have replaced the ones most likely to cause a fuse to blow, so it’s probably something else causing that. You can use an ohmmeter to check for shorts on the power rails, it would have been a good thing to do while you had the caps out. Power transistors, regulators an power amp ICs are the most likely thing to short. Try that before replacing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The goop doesn't look like glue and the other caps aren't glued, so it's probably capacitor goop.

Next thing to check would be the power input stage and the power transistor on the heatsink. However if that one is dead it may have killed your newly replaced caps.

Also check the input voltage as it might also be a bad transformer.

This board looks cheap, it might not be worth repairing.